# How do I load a React/React Router site without using a web server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I need to get a react with react router website running without getting served to a web server so my higher ups can look up on it. As per my boss' instruction, I am tasked to send him the `index.html` file with all the compiled static files(js/css/img) to load on it so they can view my work.

I have already told my boss that I can send him the site with the `package.json` on so all he has to do is run `npm install` to get the dependencies and run the script to startup the dev server, however, he has told me that he has to present it to people who will not have `node` installed. What should I do?

Comment: Bundle it all up, like you would for... production? And just deliver those few files? How come you know how to deal wtih `npm`, `node` and even React, yet you don't have fundamental understanding of what they all produce? It's not a criticism, it's just that you have the hard part done but the simple part is what's not clicking with you.

Comment: give him the files he wants

Comment: @Mjh I have bundled the file for production and gave it to him. Problem is once he opened up the `index.html` on a browser file nothing came up

Comment: So, you didn't test it first before handing it over? That sounds like your fault my friend.

Answer (score 5):

With `react-router` v4.x.x you can use `<HashRouter />`

```
import { HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

<HashRouter>
  <App/>
</HashRouter>
```

For further information [see the following link](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter)

with `react-router` v3.x.x use `hasHistory`:

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { hashHistory, Router, Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router'

import App from '../components/App'
import Home from '../components/Home'

render(
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path='/' component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={Home} />
    </Route>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

For further information [see the following link](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/guides/Histories.md#hashhistory)

You can load `react-router` as well as `react` by using `unpkg`:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router@4.2.0/umd/react-router.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you may try adding `"homepage": "."` to your project package.json; this will instruct react scripts to set all paths relative to index.html.

Of course, this won't work if your website is comunicating with a server backend or have client-side routing logic ( as it seems ). create-react docs mentions react-router [basename prop](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter/basename-string) to fix the client-side routing issue ...